# Nginx failing to authenticate JavaScript fetch using basic auth (error 401)

Tags: javascript, nginx

I am trying to use an example I found to fetch json data from my website.  It is failing to authenticate.  I can watch the error 401 on the nginx access.log.  I have tested the user:password using http fetch on my browser and the json does return.  I suspect the issue has to be a headers problem but I am not certain how to debug this.

I have added the this code to the nginx config file:

```
#Define Access-Control
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "mydomain";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "application/json";
```

Here is the JavaScript I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fetch with Basic Access Authentication</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />-->
    <style>
        p{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Fetch with Basic Access Authentication</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <p>Response will appear here after you click.</p>
    </main>
    <script>
        let p;
        
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
            function(){
                p = document.querySelector('main>p');
                p.addEventListener('click', doFetch);
            });
        
        function doFetch(ev){
            let uri = "https://mydomain";
            
            let h = new Headers();
            h.append('Accept', 'application/json');
            let encoded = window.btoa('user:password');
            let auth = 'Basic ' + encoded;
            h.append('Authorization', auth );
            console.log( auth );
            
            let req = new Request(uri, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: h,
                credentials: 'include'
            });
            //credentials: 'same-origin'
            
            fetch(req)
            .then( (response)=>{
                if(response.ok){
                    return response.json();
                }else{
                    throw new Error('BAD HTTP stuff');
                }
            })
            .then( (jsonData) =>{
                console.log(jsonData);
                p.textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4);
            })
            .catch( (err) =>{
                console.log('ERROR:', err.message);
            });
        }
        

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you specify the username and password for the authentication?

Comment: @Barmar  The username and password are entered in the encode variable  let encoded = window.btoa('user:password');

Comment: I mean where on the server?

Comment: None of the `Access-Control-Allow-XXX` settings you show have anything to do with user authentication. They're related to CORS.

Comment: @Barmar   In /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain  I have the  the basic auth configured.                                                                                                   
               #Define nginx basic authentication
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

Comment: And does the username and password there match what you're sending?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar  The username / password do match.  However they are Base64 encoded.   I can login to the site on https with no issues.   I am perusing the nginx basic auth again and see that there is a section on api access with basic auth.  I expect to find the answer there.  Regards